# How can I fire the 'onbeforeunload' event with javascript when changing views in AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJs app with two ng-views.
I have already hooked the 'onbeforeunload' event and it works great when trying to navigate outside the current page or refresh it, etc.

The problem that this dialog isn't jumping when I navigate to the other view.

How can I fire the 'onbeforeunload' event when switching ng-views?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen `$locationChangeSuccess` event for route changes.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope,$window) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        $window.trigger('beforeunload'); //then trigger beforeunload from here
    });
});
```

Comment: @ateamateam does it helpful to you

Comment: I got the error $window.trigger is not a function.. how are we supposed to trigger the event?